# SQL query for all the days of a month

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following table RENTAL(book_date, copy_id, member_id, title_id, act_ret_date, exp_ret_date). Where book_date shows the day the book was booked. I need to write a query that for every day of the month(so from 1-30 or from 1-29 or from 1-31 depending on month) it shows me the number of books booked.  
 
i currently know how to show the number of books rented in the days that are in the table

```
select count(book_date), to_char(book_date,'DD')
from rental
group by to_char(book_date,'DD');
```

my questions are:

1. How do i show the rest of the days(if let's say for some reason in my database i have no books rented on 20th or 19th or multiple days) and put the number 0 there?
2. How do i show the number of days only of the current month so(28,29,30,31 all these 4 are possible depending on month or year)... i am lost . This must be done using only SQL query no pl/SQL or other stuff.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating the database platform you are using.

Comment: Use a calendar table and then do a `LEFT JOIN` with the rental table

Comment: You say no PL/SQL, are you on Oracle?

Comment: yes on Oracle. I am using Oracle SQL Developer 12G

Comment: is there a pre-built calendar table or i have to make a script and populate a table like that?

Comment: SQL can't just create a range of dates unless your RDMS has a function for it(I'm not aware of any that do.)  Your only hope is to create a table with dates in it or write a custom function to create a date range.

Comment: @Lucian Do you want to print the total number of books rented on the current month Am  right?

Comment: well this is homework from my pl/sql course but it's from revision so i am not allowed to use anything except sql query ... i can't see how i can do this last problem either tbh , a calendar table would be ok but i don't think i am allowed to make another table. Maybe if i say there are always 31 days to show ? i show how many were rented in the days that i find in rental , how do i show for the rest that are not in rental ?

Comment: @Hardik No, i want my query to show me the total number of books rented every day (so on the 19th i have 5 books on the 20th i have 3 books and so on) and for every day that no books have been rented i want it to show me 0 and the day

Comment: but how many months of data do you want Only current month?????

Comment: All the months that i have in the table rented , i just have to count on days :D . The code that i've written in the description of the problem is ok i just need to show that for all the days that are not in RENTED the number of rented books is 0

Comment: jafar gave me all i need to solve this thank you very much for your interest @Hardik i really appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following query would give you all days in the current month, in your case you can replace `SYSDATE` with your date column and join with this query to know how many for a given month

```
SELECT DT
FROM(
SELECT TRUNC (last_day(SYSDATE) - ROWNUM) dt
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 32
  )
  where DT >= trunc(sysdate,'mm')
```

Comment: THANK YOU mr jafar this is the part i need to solve my problem , thank you very much !

Comment: you are missing +1 (TRUNC (last_day(SYSDATE) - ROWNUM) + 1). a shorter version would be: SELECT TRUNC (last_day(TO_DATE('201708','YYYYMM')) - ROWNUM + 1) dat
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < to_char (last_day(TO_DATE('201708','YYYYMM')),'DD')+1;

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to create a table like this:

table yearsmonthsdays (year varchar(4), month varchar(2), day varchar(2));

use any language you wish, e.g. iterate in java with Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) to get the last day of the month for as many years and months as you like, and fill that table with the year, month and days from 1 to last day of month of your result.

you'd get something like:

```
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1995','02','01');
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1995','02','02');
...
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1995','02','28'); /* non-leap year */
...
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1996','02','01');
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1996','02','02');
...
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1996','02','28'); 
insert into yearsmonthsdays ('1996','02','29'); /* leap year */
...
```

and so on.

Once you have this table done, your work is almost finished. Make an outer left join between your table and this table, joining year, month and day together, and when no lines appear, the count will be zero as you wish. Without using programming, this is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you Luis but it seems dual was all i needed :D

Comment: I've written this before I knew it was oracle - this solution is more database agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

In [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), you can query from `dual` and use the `conncect by level` syntax to generate a series of rows - in your case, dates. From there on, it's just a matter of deciding what dates you want to display (in my example I used all the dates from 2014) and joining on your table:

```
SELECT    all_date, COALESCE (cnt, 0)
FROM      (SELECT to_date('01/01/2014', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + rownum - 1 AS all_date
           FROM   dual
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365) d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   TRUNC(book_date), COUNT(book_date) AS cnt
           FROM     rental
           GROUP BY book_date) r ON d.all_date = TRUNC(r.book_date)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest also @Mureinik . Your answer also makes me solve my problem . I wasn't very good at explaining what i needed. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to get `ROWNUM` involved ... you can just use `LEVEL` in the `CONNECT BY`:

```
WITH d1 AS (
     SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 1 + LEVEL AS book_date
       FROM dual
    CONNECT BY TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 1 + LEVEL <= LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)
)
SELECT TRUNC(d1.book_date), COUNT(r.book_date)
  FROM d1 LEFT JOIN rental r
    ON TRUNC(d1.book_date) = TRUNC(r.book_date)
 GROUP BY TRUNC(d1.book_date);
```

Simply replace `SYSDATE` with a date in the month you're targeting for results.

Answer (score 0):

All days of the month based on current date

```
select trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) - 1)+level-1 x from dual connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(sysdate),'DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

It did works to me:

```
SELECT DT
  FROM (SELECT TRUNC(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) - (CASE WHEN ROWNUM=1 THEN 0 ELSE ROWNUM-1 END)) DT
           FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 32)
 WHERE DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL the query must look like this to not miss the last day of month:

```
SELECT DT
FROM(
SELECT trunc(add_months(sysdate, 1),'MM')- ROWNUM dt
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 32
)
where DT >= trunc(sysdate,'mm')
```